# vscode TextEditor id

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When writing a vs code extension, is there a way to get an **Unique Id for a Text Editor**? I am writing a vs code extension that requires saving some information about other Text Editors, so I wanted to map information with that for easy access. The best I have right now is using `document.filename`, which kind of works, but not exactly in the way that I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best you can get is the document URI (`document.uri`), which is also used internally by vscode to address a particular editor (which also works for virtual documents via previewHTML or git revisions).